# How do I access string-array item attributes in XAML xamarin

Tags: arrays, xamarin, xamarin.android

Is it possible to access the attributes of `string-array` item when `Spinner` get selected?
I have the following string-array:

```
<string-array name="paypal_selling_rates">
        <item fee="0.026">Under $2,500</item>
        <item fee="0.022">$2,500.01 - $5,000</item>
        <item fee="0.020">$5,000.01 - $15,000</item>
        <item fee="0.015">$15,000.01 - $150,000</item>
        <item fee="0.011">Over $150,000</item>
    </string-array>
```

Now i can get the value of selected item like this:

```
paypalSellingRates.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

But how I can access the attribute fee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an Android question. On Android, string array resources can't have attributes on the items.

So the answer is that you can't.

Read more about this in the [official Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray).

Comment: That would be unfortunate.